# What compares to Finagle and Akka in the ruby world?

Tags: ruby, akka, finagle

I was reading up on Finagle and Akka, and was wondering if there are any similar frameworks in the ruby world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of these is what you are looking for?

http://celluloid.io/

http://cramp.in/

http://postrank-labs.github.io/goliath/